# ckeditor + media wiki

Tags: php, ckeditor

i searched alot  but didnt find  a tutorial on how to install ckeditor for media wiki

i asked there but no one answered  , im sure , i should ask here , but as you are professionals maybe know it

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, you can integrate CKEditor's precedessor, FCKEditor, with MediaWiki: [**MediaWiki+FCKEditor**](http://mediawiki.fckeditor.net/)

As far as I can see, there is a successor project underway (See discussion [**here**](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12819&start=10)):

> Yes, we'll be working on MediaWiki+CKEditor. It will not happen before the final stable CKEditor 3.0 release though.

But as far as I can see, it has not been released yet. Integration does not seem to be entirely trivial, because CKEditor would actually have to produce *different code* that works with MediaWiki.

You may have to go with FCKEditor for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is old but I've been looking to integrate CKEditor for a while now and there is very little information concerning this on the net!  For anyone else who might be looking:

I found this on MediaWiki in FCKEditor section of the [WYSIWYG_editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/WYSIWYG_editor#Proof_of_concept%3a_WYSIWYG_Editors) page:

> Ontoprise's halo team is maintaining a production quality integration
>   of MediaWiki and CKEditor: [Extension:WYSIWYG](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWYSIWYG).

I installed it on our MediaWiki (v.1.16) and so far it works like a charm!